# Xcode crashes when trying to specify Developer Team in Organizer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to release my first app onto the iTunes Store, but Xcode keeps crashing when I try to distribute it.

I go to: `Window > Organizer` then click on the app's archive and select `Distribute`.

After that, I:

1. select `Submit to iOS App Store`
2. log into my developer account
3. click on `Download Identities` under `Connect to iOS Dev Center`
4. select my development team/account then click `Choose`

After #4, Xcode crashes. I've tried it multiple times and it keeps crashing.

Am I doing this wrong?

I just updated to the latest version of Xcode 5.0 with support of iOS7.

**Edit #2**

It looks like there's a `Submit` button that appears that you can just click on. I'm not getting that button. Is it available for 5.0? Or maybe I did something wrong when setting up my app on iTunes Connect?

http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2

**Edit**

Here is the dump:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8ebf4510 objc_msgSend_vtable5 + 16
1   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d13c3b2 +[NSTextInputContext currentInputContext] + 128
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d13bb81 -[NSApplication updateWindows] + 94
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d386d9f __38-[NSApplication setWindowsNeedUpdate:]_block_invoke_02349 + 76
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8e53d417 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8e53d381 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 369
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8e5187b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 728
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8e5180e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8fea3eb4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
9   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8fea3b94 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 166
10  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8fea3ae3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d13a533 _DPSNextEvent + 685
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d139df2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d1311a3 -[NSApplication run] + 517
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d0d5bd6 NSApplicationMain + 869
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff902167e1 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff902a7d16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff863a4dea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff863a49ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8e349cfc OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64Barrier$VARIANT$mp + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8e360886 __mtx_droplock + 432
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8e361195 pthread_mutex_unlock + 268
3   com.apple.security              0x00007fff8f552d95 Security::Mutex::unlock() + 9
4   com.apple.security              0x00007fff8f553eb0 Security::CFClass::refCountForType(long, void const*) + 116
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8e4ec324 CFRelease + 324
6   com.apple.security              0x00007fff8f6b6e03 _possibleRootCertificatesForOidString(__CFString const*) + 1251
7   com.apple.security              0x00007fff8f5843fc allowedEVRootsForLeafCertificate + 506
8   com.apple.security              0x00007fff8f5835a1 Security::KeychainCore::Trust::evaluate(bool) + 77
9   com.apple.security              0x00007fff8f583464 SecTrustEvaluate + 53
10  com.apple.security              0x00007fff8f5de034 sslCopyPeerPubKey + 42
11  com.apple.security              0x00007fff8f5aed12 SSLProcessCertificate + 475
12  com.apple.security              0x00007fff8f5da795 SSLProcessHandshakeMessage + 233
13  com.apple.security              0x00007fff8f5a7d53 SSLProcessHandshakeRecord + 223
14  com.apple.security              0x00007fff8f5a7c21 SSLProcessProtocolMessage + 107
15  com.apple.security              0x00007fff8f5a7526 SSLHandshakeProceed + 374
16  com.apple.security              0x00007fff8f5a7397 SSLHandshake + 134
17  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff8f234111 SocketStream::_PerformSecurityHandshake_NoLock() + 133
18  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff8f23302d SocketStream::socketCallback(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*) + 145
19  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff8f232f81 SocketStream::_SocketCallBack_stream(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*, void*) + 83
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8e534fa5 __CFSocketPerformV0 + 1045
21  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8e4f5b31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
22  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8e4f5455 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 245
23  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8e5187f5 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
24  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8e5180e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
25  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff90c56546 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 356
26  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff90cb4562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
27  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8e35b7a2 _pthread_start + 327
28  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8e3481e1 thread_start + 13
```

Comment: what s the error message?

Comment: It just says `Xcode quit unexpectedly`. I put in the dump but it doesn't make much sense to me. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to reboot your mac?

Comment: Just tried. it still crashes. :(

Comment: Have you tried clearing out all the identities and all developer information there and downloading them again? Something happened between xcode 4 and xcode 5 and i needed to reimport them from the apple site and then into xcode

Comment: Apple bug. Make sure to open a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem and just resolved it.

Because of this bug in Xcode you can't update the profiles from within Xcode. You have to log into the Dev Center, go to Provisioning Profiles, and make the Distribution profile for this app.

After you've done that, Xcode will be able to submit your app without crashing.

Comment: I got this working a few weeks ago doing this, but I forgot to post on this question. :)